# how to get touches of uiimage view in scrollview and perform some action

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a scrollview with uiimageview1 added on it. On click on that uiimageview1 I want to present a viewcontroller to make some drawing. After drawing, I want to take picture of that drawing and place it on uiimageview1.
i don't know how to and where do i present that viewcontroller for drawing.
please help.

Answer (score 0):

So, first you need to detect touches on your imageView. To do that you need to use `UIGestureRecognizer` or `UIButton`.

Then, you need to present a new view controller using the `presentViewController:animated:completion:` method of your current `UIViewController` (passing it the 'drawing' view controller).

After the drawing is performed, you can use iOS delegation pattern to notify the original view controller that you just drew something.
The original view controller handles that 'delegated event' and updates the image view accordingly.

[`UIViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html) and [`UIButton`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html) documentations are here for you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIButton with uiimageview.layer.bounds and add it as subview to uiimageview

Make the button background color `[UIColor clearColor]`
Add a @selector to button and push newViewController with segue or add it programaticaly from UINavigation Controller stack.

Otherwise you can make a pan gesture recognizer to UIImageView and listen for user interaction TAP on screen for pushing the new view controller

Answer (score 0):

You can Simply do this by adding UITapGestureRecognizer properties to your image view.
Like:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(presentViewController)];
[self.yourImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];


-(void)presentViewController{
// do remain stuff
```

}

Happy Codding :)